# Managing multiple threads with Main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm initializing and starting five threads in my Testing Class:

```
[Test]        
public void ReportGeneratorFiveThreadTest()
{
    var threads = new List<ReportGeneratorThread>();
    var logger = new Log4NetLogger(typeof(ReportGeneratorThreadTest));

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var estimatedReportSize = EstimatedReportSize.Normal;
        var thread = new ReportGeneratorThread(logger, new ReportGenerator(20), estimatedReportSize, new ManualResetEvent(false));
        thread.Name = string.Format("ReportGeneratorThread{0}", i);
        threads.Add(thread);
    }
    threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());          
}
```

And I'm starting all threads by calling following method in ReportGeneratorThread class:

```
public void Start()
    {
        this.running = true;
        this.t = new Thread(this.GenerateReport());
        this.t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        this.t.Start();
    }
```

Which calls a GenerateReport() method in order to perform an operation:

```
public void GenerateReport()
    {
        var didwork = false;
        try
        {
            didwork = this.reportGenerator.GenerateReport(this.estimatedReportSize);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.log.LogError(ReportGenerator.CorrelationIdForPickingReport, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error during report generation."), 0, e);
            this.doneEvent.Reset();
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread is aborted !!!");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!didwork)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.ReportGenerationInterval);
            }
        }
    }
```

My purpose is to inform my main thread once a thread among all five threads gets aborted (an exception is thrown in GenerateReport() method) and restart it in my main thread afterwards. I have tried using ManualResetEvent for that purpose, but it seems like it is not the proper class to use for this purpose. Any approaches ?.

Comment: Is it an option to use Tasks instead of Threads?

Comment: I'll prefer to avoid that if there are other opportunities

Comment: Why not simply retry the operation inside the GenerateReport method if an exception is thrown? why do you want to move such decision to the main thread?

Comment: Just store the exception object in a variable.  Waiting for all threads to completely with a MRE is fine, a CountDownEvent is simpler.  Don't abort anything, it is already bad enough that you are contemplating restarting it when code died with an unhandled exception.  No point in optimizing crashing code.  And do keep in mind that an object that requires STA is not that likely to behave well when you use them on multiple threads anyway.  That was never tested by the programmer, his static variables won't be thread-safe.